# select the date only from date datatype to show in dropdown list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I make a query under dropdown list to show the date from date datatype.
Here is the query/code in the visual studio.

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select cast(timestamp_Instance as varchar(12)) from Instance1", con);
con.open();
```

i tried above query and the output is correct.

Below is the screenshot of the table

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8VCG.png)

Below is screenshot of the output in dropdown list

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6tb0.png)

This my code to bind the values in the dropdown list but i got an error after trying this. The erro is :System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'timestamp_Instance'

```
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select cast(timestamp_Instance as varchar(12)) from Instance1", con);

            con.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "timestamp_Instance";
           DropDownList1.DataBind();
           con.Close();
```

Comment: `select * from date` will return an error unless you happen to have a table called `date`.  If that's the case, we'd need to see what columns were in the table and what their data types were.

Comment: i edited my post @AnnL.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select cast(timestamp_Instanc as varchar(12))
```

So your code will look like :

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select cast(timestamp_Instanc as varchar(12)) from table1", con); con.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess, I'll suggest you to typecast your value as DateTime and take only the Date part. For example:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var onlyDate = DateTime.Date;
```

Comment: i edited my codes after trying one of the query that being suggested which i can get the date only in the sql query. but error after editing in visual studio of the query